# How to zoom or out image follow mouse position?use image element(scale、top、left)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don’t know how to calculate the movement of the picture when it is zoom out or zoom in

Let the picture produce the feeling of zooming in or out from the mouse position, and have a natural excessive effect

The effect is similar to this

https://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/

https://github.com/jackmoore/wheelzoom

But I have to use "div" and "img" element

demo
https://i.imgur.com/hBRII3X.mp4

code is like this

```js
const imageDiv = document.getElementById("imageDiv");
  const image = document.getElementById("image");
  const max = 10, min = 1, step = 0.2;
  let startX = 0, startY = 0, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0, holding = false;

  function setImageTopAndLeft(image, left, top) {
    const scale = parseFloat(image.dataset.scale); // current scale ratio
    let currentLeft = (image.dataset.prevleft) ? parseInt(image.dataset.prevleft) : 0; // prev left value
    let currentTop = (image.dataset.prevtop) ? parseInt(image.dataset.prevtop) : 0; // prev top value
    let { width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight } = image.getBoundingClientRect();
    let { width: constraintWidth, height: constraintHeight } = imageDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
    let maxOffsetLeft = 0; // left max value
    let maxOffsetTop = 0; // top max value

    if (scale > 1) {
      maxOffsetLeft = (imageWidth - constraintWidth) / 2; // left max value
      maxOffsetTop = (imageHeight - constraintHeight) / 2; // top max value

      let offsetLeft = left + currentLeft; // offset left value
      let offsetTop = top + currentTop; // offset top value

      if (maxOffsetLeft > 0) {
        if (offsetLeft >= maxOffsetLeft) {
          offsetLeft = maxOffsetLeft;
        } else if (offsetLeft <= -1 * maxOffsetLeft) {
          offsetLeft = -1 * maxOffsetLeft;
        } else {
          offsetLeft = offsetLeft * 1;
        }
        image.style.left = offsetLeft + "px";
      }

      if (maxOffsetTop > 0) {
        if (offsetTop >= maxOffsetTop) {
          offsetTop = maxOffsetTop;
        } else if (offsetTop <= -1 * maxOffsetTop) {
          offsetTop = -1 * maxOffsetTop;
        } else {
          offsetTop = offsetTop * 1;
        }
        image.style.top = offsetTop + "px";
      }
    }
  }

  function wheel(event) {

    let ratio = parseFloat(image.dataset.scale);

    if (event.deltaY < 0) { // 放大
      ratio = ratio + step;
    }

    if (event.deltaY > 0) { // 縮小
      ratio = ratio - step;
    }

    if (ratio > max) {
      ratio = max;
    }

    if (ratio < min) {
      ratio = min
    }

    image.dataset.scale = ratio.toFixed(2);

    image.style.transform = `scale(${ratio.toFixed(2)})`

  }

  image.onload = () => {

    imageDiv.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
      wheel(event);
    })

    imageDiv.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      holding = true;
      startX = event.pageX;
      startY = event.pageY;
    })

    imageDiv.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (holding) {
        offsetX = event.pageX - startX;
        offsetY = event.pageY - startY;
        setImageTopAndLeft(image, offsetX, offsetY);
      }
    })

    imageDiv.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      holding = false;
      startX = 0;
      startY = 0;
      image.dataset.prevleft = parseInt(image.style.left);
      image.dataset.prevtop = parseInt(image.style.top);
    })
    
  }
```

```css
div {
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* child image vertical center */
    justify-items: center;
    /* child image horizontal  center */
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: blue;
  }

  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    /*Adapt to different proportions of pictures*/
    max-height: 100%;
    /*Adapt to different proportions of pictures*/
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    /*mouse move change this value or wheel zoom then follow mouse position change this value*/
    left: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
    /*wheel zoom or out scale image*/
  }
```

```html
  <div id="imageDiv">
    <img data-prevleft="0" data-prevtop="0" data-scale="1" id="image"
      src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1637249833220-d399eb65e802?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80">
  </div>
```

jsfiddle demo link: https://jsfiddle.net/0b6qaLgz/2/

sorry my english is bad

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
 <div id="container">
  <div id="slide">
    <img src="https://iso.500px.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/big-one.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#slide{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transition: transform .3s;
}
img{
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var scroll_zoom = new ScrollZoom($('#container'),4,0.5)
})


function ScrollZoom(container,max_scale,factor){
    var target = container.children().first()
    var size = {w:target.width(),h:target.height()}
    var pos = {x:0,y:0}
    var zoom_target = {x:0,y:0}
    var zoom_point = {x:0,y:0}
    var scale = 1
    target.css('transform-origin','0 0')
    target.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll",scrolled)

    function scrolled(e){
        var offset = container.offset()
        zoom_point.x = e.pageX - offset.left
        zoom_point.y = e.pageY - offset.top

        e.preventDefault();
        var delta = e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        if (delta === undefined) {
          //we are on firefox
          delta = e.originalEvent.detail;
        }
        delta = Math.max(-1,Math.min(1,delta)) // cap the delta to [-1,1] for cross browser consistency

        // determine the point on where the slide is zoomed in
        zoom_target.x = (zoom_point.x - pos.x)/scale
        zoom_target.y = (zoom_point.y - pos.y)/scale

        // apply zoom
        scale += delta*factor * scale
        scale = Math.max(1,Math.min(max_scale,scale))

        // calculate x and y based on zoom
        pos.x = -zoom_target.x * scale + zoom_point.x
        pos.y = -zoom_target.y * scale + zoom_point.y


        // Make sure the slide stays in its container area when zooming out
        if(pos.x>0)
            pos.x = 0
        if(pos.x+size.w*scale<size.w)
            pos.x = -size.w*(scale-1)
        if(pos.y>0)
            pos.y = 0
         if(pos.y+size.h*scale<size.h)
            pos.y = -size.h*(scale-1)

        update()
    }

    function update(){
        target.css('transform','translate('+(pos.x)+'px,'+(pos.y)+'px) scale('+scale+','+scale+')')
    }
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xta2ccdt/13/)

Comment: Make the web of the "jsfiddle demo link" the same zoom effect as "https://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/"

Comment: think this is what you need

Comment: So I can't set top and left to achieve the same result?

Comment: Is the calculation principle convenient to explain?